# WPF ToggleButton Background issue

Tags: c#, togglebutton, wpf-style

When I apply a style to ToggleButton for changing the content depending on the toggleButton state, the background image is not shown.

The idea is that I have an image, and when it's clicked I want to add a color filter to the image.

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="tgStyle">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#55838383"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0"  >
                        <Rectangle Fill="#50A52A2A" Width="30" Height="30" />
                    </Border>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Border  BorderThickness="0" >
                                <Rectangle Fill="#55FF0000" Width="30" Height="30" />
                            </Border>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Width="30" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=tgStyle}">
                <ToggleButton.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/bg_cig.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </ToggleButton.Background>  
            </ToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Border  BorderThickness="0" >
                <Rectangle Fill="#55FF0000" Width="30" Height="30" />
            </Border>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

You will have to use `DataTrigger`.

For usage of `Trigger`, `DataTrigger` and `EventTrigger` Please refer this tutorial.

[Trigger, DataTrigger & EventTrigger - The complete WPF tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/)

Comment: What's happening? you are supposed to get a red background.

Comment: this is not the problem,i need to apply a color filter to the background image,so i need to superpose the content with the background to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

i get it working by doing some modifications in my style and components

```
<Style x:Key="myToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="outer"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Opacity=".5"
        Background="Transparent"/>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="outer" Property="Background" Value="#50F0"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="outer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

and the compenents:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Resources/bg_cig.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myToggleButton}"/>
        <Image Source="Resources/bg_cig.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myToggleButton}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```